# Screen reader (JAWS) is reading parent page controls

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I am using Kendo windows in my application. Whenever I am opening a Kendo window and try to access the application using JAWS screen reader.  The screen reader is able to read parent page control information like menu, even though the Kendo window opened through a modal popup. I am able to stop navigation for parent controls by using tab for following code but not able to hide screen from screen reader.

How can I force JAWS to look at the content of the modal popup?

```
onActivate(e) {
    var self: any = this;
    var windowElement = self.wrapper,
    windowContent = self.element;
    $(document).on("keydown.kendoWindow", function (e) {
    var focusedElement = $(document.activeElement);
    if (e.keyCode == kendo.keys.TAB && 
    focusedElement.closest(windowElement).length == 0) 
        {
             windowContent.focus();
         }
    });
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put more effort into grammar because your post is nearly impossible to understand.

Comment: modified some grammar. If still there are issues in understanding the question please let me know.

Comment: What is the element you are trying to move focus to? You might need to add tabindex=-1 to make it focusable via JavaScript.

Comment: @MadhavHatwalne - yes, much better! Good job :)

Comment: @Campinho No issues with focus main issue is though I restricted focus screen reader is still able to access fields behind the popup

Answer (score 0):

By setting attribute value ARIA-Hidden = true I was able to achieve desired functionality